# (Done) Reopen 'Can an employer deduct "scam losses" from wages?'

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

Can the following question be reopened: [Can an employer deduct "scam losses" from wages?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/189407/can-an-employer-deduct-scam-losses-from-wages)?

I do not see anything employer-specific in this question, and the question has been updated to specify a jurisdiction.

Comment: I suspect this is one of those "Questions seeking legal advice " that doesn't belong on The Workplace.

Comment: While it *should* be something HR or accounting should know without a law degree, I can no longer cast normal votes and I think it would be a bad look to use mod powers in a question I have participated in as a normal user. I will leave it to the others to vote their way.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I still think it's a valid question for this SE. Either way, the current close reason is incorrect, since this isn't something to do with "company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies."

Comment: @zmike - part of the close reason says "Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals. " I voted to reopen long ago.

Comment: Yes, it seems that people don't understand what legal advice means. Stating what the laws say of a particular jurisdiction is not legal advice.

Comment: After reading the question and answers it looks valid enough to me so I'll make a judgement call on it.

Answer (score 2):

Migrate the question to law.

While legal advice is off-topic there, "can an employer do this?" is completely fine.